# Why does my old file contents get overwritten?

Tags: android

i'm using the below code to save log data to a file.
However, every time a new call is made, the old content is gone.....

i can't figure out what the issue is however....

```
public void writeToFile(String fileName, String textToWrite) {

        FileOutputStream fOut = null;
        try {

            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() , fileName);
            if (! root.exists()){
                root.createNewFile();
            }

            fOut = new FileOutputStream(root);
            OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            myOutWriter.append(textToWrite);
            myOutWriter.flush();
            myOutWriter.close();   
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            new MailService().mailMessage(e.toString());
        }
        finally{

            if(fOut != null){
                try{
                    fOut.close();
                }
                catch(Exception ex){

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass second parameter boolean `true` to `FileOutputStream` constructor which indicates the file will be opened in append mode rather than write mode.

```
FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream("myfile");
```

Everytime you execute the above code it will open the file in write mode so that the new content will overwrite the old content. However, the `FileOutputStream` constructor accepts a second argument which is a `boolean` indicating whether to open the file in append mode.

```
FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream("myfile",true);
```

The above code will open the file in append mode so that the new content will be appended to the end of old content.

To know more about `FileOutputStream` constructors see [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29).

Comment: Wooot! sometimes you read through so many code examples you miss what is what, so thanks for the answer, this did the trick!